# ModelFactory: Error: Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, phpunit, lumen

While trying to populate database using ModelFactory I am coming across this bit of error, I have been looking up since the last six hours, can not seem to fix it.

My Test runs this:

```
$books = factory('App\Book', 2)->create();
```

and the error message is this:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\App\Http\Controllers\BooksControllerTest::testIndexReturnsCollection
Error: Call to a member function connection() on null

D:\Code\Server\htdocs\rlfp.localhost.com\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php:1234
D:\Code\Server\htdocs\rlfp.localhost.com\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php:1200
D:\Code\Server\htdocs\rlfp.localhost.com\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php:1030
D:\Code\Server\htdocs\rlfp.localhost.com\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php:945
D:\Code\Server\htdocs\rlfp.localhost.com\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php:983
D:\Code\Server\htdocs\rlfp.localhost.com\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:203
D:\Code\Server\htdocs\rlfp.localhost.com\vendor\illuminate\support\Collection.php:407
D:\Code\Server\htdocs\rlfp.localhost.com\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:207
D:\Code\Server\htdocs\rlfp.localhost.com\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:185
D:\Code\Server\htdocs\rlfp.localhost.com\tests\app\Http\Controllers\BooksControllerTest.php:35
```

On my bootstrap/app.php I have on line 26 and 28, like so:

```
$app->withFacades();

$app->withEloquent();
```

While my phpunit.xml is like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/app.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="rlp_rlfpsfactory"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Do I need to put anything else in the php part of phpunit xml file?

Comment: I've been battling with this one for a couple of days. Appears to be a bug in Lumen 5.7 as once I downgraded tp 5.6 it's working.

Comment: @ChrisSprague that worked! I simply deleted my vendor folder, changed lumen version in composer.json, composer install, and then it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending one whole day with no luck, thanks to @ChrisSprague I downgraded Lumen to 5.6 and it worked.

Steps:

1. In composer.json file change

   ```
   "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.7.*"
   ```

   to

   ```
   "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.6.*"
   ```
2. Delete your `vendor` folder
3. Do `composer install`
4. Run the test again!

If it still does not work, make sure you have correct test database details in your `phpunit.xml` file

Mine looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/app.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="rlp_rlfpsfactory"/> <!-- this is testing database -->
        <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="root"/>
        <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value=""/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```